# Displaying different jpeg images in their natural proportion to one another using EXIF data

Tags: php, css, image, scale, exif

On a PHP based website, i would like to display uploaded images of insects in their natural proportion to one another: even though the image of an ant and the image of a bumblebee have the same resolution, the absolute count of screen-pixels should differ, the image of the bumblebee should be displayed larger.
How can i scale the images automatically with PHP/CSS? Can I use EXIF data? Maybe there are already existing solutions, but i didn't find them online.

Comment: PHP and CSS are wildly different topics. Both can scale an image, just one uses server resources, and the other uses browser resources. For PHP, I would recommend Imagick/ImageMagick or the SimpleImage class on Github. For CSS it's easy as saying something like ```img { width:200px; }``` Could you be more specific with your question?

Comment: That's not the point, maybe my question was misleading: I know css/html very well, but i have to use metadata of the image to give it a proportional scale, it's the printing dimension of the image I am interested in, not the resolution.